# How to add number to port in GoJS?

Tags: javascript, gojs

Hi I need to add number to each of ports as you see in the picture below. 
Ps. How ever I looking for resolve the problem on this site https://gojs.net/latest/intro/ports.html and I check solution with `portId` and `TextBlock` but it doesn't work :/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using a Shape for a port, but any GoJS object can be a port, and you really want to use a Panel (Auto Panel) with a Shape and a TextBlock as your port.

I suggest you read: https://gojs.net/latest/intro/buildingObjects.html

Answer (score 0):

Hi thank you for your Answer :) hmm I try to use a Panel but I don't see change :/ What I do wrong?

```
this.$(go.Panel, 'Horizontal',
  new go.Binding('itemArray', 'bottomArray'),
  {
    row: 2, column: 1,
    itemTemplate:
      this.$(go.Panel, 'Vertical',
        {
          _side: 'bottom',
          fromSpot: go.Spot.Bottom, toSpot: go.Spot.Bottom, fromMaxLinks: 1,
          fromLinkable: true, toLinkable: false, cursor: 'pointer'
        },
        new go.Binding('portId', 'portId'),

        this.$(go.Shape, 'RoundedRectangle',
          {
            stroke: null, strokeWidth: 0,
            desiredSize: portSize,
            margin: new go.Margin(2, 1, 0, 1)
          },
          new go.Binding('fill', 'portColor')),
        this.$(go.TextBlock,
          new go.Binding('text', 'name'))
      )
  }
),
```